# Are playerless match outcomes fixed?

Tags: dota-2

In Dota 2, if the players were to leave the Radiant and Dire creeps to play the game out without doing anything in game, is the fate of the match set (favored towards Dire/Radiant), or is it entirely random?

I'm just curious to see if anyone knows if a match that is played out with players on both sides not participating and letting the creeps duke it out would result in one side winning all the time or just Radiant winning some and Dire winning some?

Comment: I have not checked myself, but [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_lHG5uXN_nE) shows/claims that both dire and radiant can win with no player interaction.

Comment: The only element of random would be uphill misses of ranged creeps. I think even such small thing could favor one side over the other.

Comment: I suggest changing the title to "playerless matches", as it stands I thought it was about match fixing or something alike...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, It's random since the damage creeps inflict is actually randomized within a certain range :

**Melee**

- 19-23 for normal
- 36-44 for super
- 96-104 for mega

**Range**

- 21-26 for normal
- 41-46 for super
- 131-136 for mega

Then you have to take into account uphill misses from range creeps when they occur which are also random.

Those small random elements cause the creepwave's fight to almost always leave one creep alive thus destroying the balance of the lane leading to one team inevitably winning. However since the damage are random, which creep is left alive is not pre-determined.

Comment: Also the positioning of the creeps in the lane matters. I heard that dire had an advantage in top lane because the creeps can kill the radiant creeps faster due to better positioning.